# How to use SQLiteConnection in Windows Phone Runtime?

Tags: c#, sqlite, windows-phone-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone

I want to use SQL relationships in my Windows Phone Runtime app. So it seems I need to use `SQLite-net Extensions`

I have referenced these files:

```
 SQLite.Net 
 SQLiteNetExtensions 
 SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1
```

But when I want to get a connection:

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection( ... );
```

It requires an implementation of `ISQLitePlatform` interface. How do I get the argument value?

(It seems there is not a ready `SQLite Net Extensions` package for `Windows Phone Runtime`, if anyone knows how to get it I greatly appreciate it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is a rather new development but I think they updated their nuget package a few hours ago:

https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions/issue/27/error-while-adding-sqlite-net-extension-to

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

If you have everything installed right, the argument is just the location + file_name of the database file.  Like so:

```
string dbPath = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "db.sqlite");          

using (var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath))
{
    db.RunInTransaction(() =>
    {            
       // ....
    });
}
```

---

**db.sqlite** can be anything you want, it is just the name of a file in the storage folder (but it must exist, so you need to create it first)

---

Some useful links:

[Sqlite-for-Universal-Windows](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2014/05/08/Sqlite-for-Universal-Windows-and-Windows-Phone-applications.aspx)
[SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b?SRC=Home)

Comment: Thanks @Chubosaurus. `SQLite-net` works fine for me, but my problem is with [`SQLite-Net Extensions`](https://bitbucket.org/twincoders/sqlite-net-extensions) which is a layer on top of it to support table relationships. `SQLiteConnection` you referred to requires only a database path, but `SQLite-Net Extensions` version of that class requires an additional value: `SQLiteConnection(ISQLitePlatform sqlitePlatform, string databasePath)`

Comment: I have same issue, does anyone manage to initilise it properly?

Answer (score 0):

The SQLite.Net-PCL changed their API as of ver 3.1.1. As per their readme file in their github project:

> You now have to pass in an implementation of ISQlitePlatform in the
>   SQLiteConnectionWithLock and SQLiteConnection constructors. The
>   correct platform implementation is automatically added to the project.

This is what worked for me for a WinPhone81 project:

```
var conn = new SQLiteConnection( new SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT.SQLitePlatformWinRT(),  path);
```

I have three Nuget pkgs that are relevant:
SQLite.Net.Core-PCL (v3.1.1)
SQLite.Net-PCL (v3.1.1)
SQLiteNetExtensions (v1.3.0)

Also a library reference to SQLite for Windows Phone 8.1 (manually added as per the instructions on the SQLite.Net-PCL readme),
and a library reference to SQLite.Net.Platform.WinRT that was added by the Nuget pkg installer when I added the pkg for SQLiteNetExtensions.

This is all very reminiscent of the old style DLL hell that occurred before .Net was born. Nothing new under the sun it seems.